# Electron-builder repeatedly asks for macOS keychain permissions

Tags: xcode, code-signing-certificate, electron-builder

I am attempting to run `yarn package` against my Electron app.

I get to the "Code Signing" step and I am prompted for administrator access to my "System" keychain.

I enter my credentials and immediately represented with the prompted for credentials to access system keychain again, and again repeatedly.

I have checked and have upgraded to the latest XCode, and my Apple Developer Code-Signing Certificate is installed (?), and I have checked and my terminal `xcodebuild -version` yields the following:

```
Xcode 9.2
Build version 9C40b
```

The last output lines of the terminal are:

```
electron-builder 19.31.1
No native production dependencies
Packaging for darwin x64 using electron 1.7.3 to release/mac
Signing app (identity: 068C71CA6XXXXXXXXXXXXX gdb-cert)
```

I do not know if this is the correct `identity` matching one in my keychain - but `gdb-cert` does not seem correct?

--
Update

I have to enter the username/password combination about 2 dozen times for all framework items. There has to be a way to *always* allow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution. You can grant access for the app. Steps:

1. Open the `Keychain Access` app
2. Find the certification in the `System` keychain
3. Expand the cert and double click `private key`
4. In the `Access Control` tab, check `Allow all applications to access this item`, or add the app to the list
5. Save Changes, Done!

[image]

Comment: My unsung hero! This was bugging me real hard!

Comment: Hmm, I worry about the security implications here. Now any application on your Mac has access to this private key?